# Inclusion of TikZ package changes page dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf

For some reason, inclusion of the TikZ package in a document seems to change the page size: the bottom of the page is slightly shorter if TikZ is included. A minimal example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hi, there!
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling using pdflatex, from TeX Live 2013 (pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)). I assume that it won't make much of a difference when printing, except maybe if the page is centered. In that case, using TikZ would shift the contents of the entire page downwards a bit...

Comment: How do you know where the bottom of the page is if this is the only content on the page?

Comment: Having the pdf viewer open, and recompiling with and without \usepackage{tikz} shows the page size changing. Also, the distance from the bottom of the page to the page number changes.

Comment: @Michael Rather than relying on your browser, you could use a tool such as `pdfinfo`, which will tell you exactly what the page dimensions are.

Comment: Ah that gave me the hint to fix it. Using tikz, the page size changes from A4 to letter ... weird!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` seems to fix it. Without this, `tikz` changes the page size to letter!

Comment: Odd. I get the same. I cannot recall reading anything about this feature in the TikZ manual. I'd consider this a bug.

Comment: Same here. But with `\documentclass{scrartcl}` I get A4 (my TeXLive default setting) in either case.

Comment: @AlexG That's because `scrartcl` has `a4paper` as default, while `article` has `letterpaper`. Which means that if `\documentclass{article}` compiles with `a4paper` means that you have configured that before in the Latex instalation (or the compiler). I can't tell you more than that, and I'm not sure this is even true :S